# how to insert text outside a object in DIA?

Tags: entity-relationship, diagram, dia, conceptual-model

i'm having a little problem drawing a entity-relationship diagram with the tool DIA.  I need to insert text outside objects but the tool let me only write inside them. 
Is there a way to do it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have no problems putting text outside objects. I simply select the `text` tool, place the tool where I want it and type text. It shows up without problems.I am using Dia 0.97.2 on Windows 10.